# Accessibility - lost focus, should I force focus next focusable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, focus, accessibility

I am creating big form and would provide button navigation between sections for accessibility.

It means that you could expand/collapse next or previous section by buttons navigation.

However, when you switch section, current section is hidden (and next one is showed) by `display` CSS property, so just used button is anymore focused as it's not visible.

Take a look on **[this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zwLLrg9d/4/)** or code below to understand issue.

HTML:

```
<a href="#">An anchor</a>

<article>
    <header>First box</header>
    <main>
        This is first box.
        <label><input type="radio" class="focusable" />This is input</label>
        <button class="next focusable">Next box</button>
    </main>
</article>

<article class="box-hidden">
    <header>Second box</header>
    <main>
        This is second box.
        <button class="focusable">Extra button</button>
        <label><input type="radio" class="focusable" />This is input</label>
        <button class="prev focusable">Previous box</button>
        <button class="next focusable">Next box</button>
    </main>
</article>

<article class="box-hidden">
    <header>Third box</header>
    <main>
        This is third box.
        <label><input type="radio" class="focusable" />This is input</label>
        <button class="prev focusable">Previous box</button>
    </main>
</article>

<a href="#">An anchor</a>
```

CSS:

```
.box-hidden main {
    display: none;
}

/* Only cosmetic below */

article { background: #ddd; margin: 10px 0; }
header { background: #ccc; }

button:focus { outline: 2px solid blue; }
```

JQuery:

```
$( 'body' ).on('click', '.next', function( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var next = $( this ).closest( 'article' ).next( 'article' );

    $( 'article' ).addClass( 'box-hidden' );
    $( next ).removeClass( 'box-hidden' );
});

$( 'body' ).on('click', '.prev', function( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var prev = $( this ).closest( 'article' ).prev( 'article' );

    $( 'article' ).addClass( 'box-hidden' );
    $( prev ).removeClass( 'box-hidden' );
});
```

When you use next or previous button, focus is lost and you have to start again from page begin. It can't happen.

---

My solution is to find closest focusable *(it sucks, because I use class due first focusable could be input either another button)* in opened section and focus it:

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zwLLrg9d/6/)** or add to JQuery:

```
$( next ).find( '.focusable' )[0].focus();
```

At end of both functions, analogously replace `$( next )` to `$( prev )` in second one.

So it will look like:

```
    //[...]
    $( next ).removeClass( 'box-hidden' );

    $( next ).find( '.focusable' )[0].focus();
});
```

**But I am not sure is it right way**, isn't it confuse user navigating by focusable elements?
Maybe I should do it another way?

Note: Buttons are appended by JS, so non-JS users just dont't use them.

Thanks in advance for advices!

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve].

Comment: @TinyGiant, Yes you were right. That code was unreadable. I already cleaned both version, as much as I can.

Comment: You should [edit] those examples into your question, what would happen if those links eventually went dead? This question would make no sense to future viewers

Comment: @TinyGiant, Yes it seems like ~12 hours of programming is too much at the moment. Time go sleep. I didn't thought that if someone will find this question useful in future, it will give him nothing, because lack of code. Already fixed. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you have uncovered a usability issue, not an accessibility issue. I would replace the next and previous buttons with expand/collapse toggles for these sections. This would immediately solve your accessibility issue (because these buttons would always be visible) and it would be a UI model that users are familiar with and solve (what I believe to be) a non-standard and confusing interaction model.

Here is your JSfiddle updated for this implementation (you can probably find better icons than I used) http://jsfiddle.net/zwLLrg9d/7/

I also changed this so that there is correct use of sectioning content. Multiple instances of a `<header>` element are definitely not recommended.

Comment: I have expand/collapse also, but not included in code as it question not regarding it.
Yes, it may be familiar, BUT site is mainly directed to old people that may have no so advanced knowledge about web technologies.
This form is going to help that my client will be able to have clients that filled in whole form - then check price, order by internet or this form will help to complete order manually.

Comment: However as I have onclick (no focusing) toggling, I will consider your suggestion as it uses `input` that may be good idea - no empty anchor link or button with strange text to text readers.

Comment: Note that I simplied to `<header>`'s for Tiny Giant request as code was unreadable. I use only div's there as it is not kind of content, but form.

Comment: I hope it is useful to you :-)